# Accessing Delegate in Subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c

I searched around for this but couldn't find any answer that works.. How do I successfully access the delegate methods from a subclass?

Like so:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@protocol customMapViewDelegate <MKMapViewDelegate>
//
@end

@interface customSubClass : MKMapView <MKMapViewDelegate>
//
@end
```

Basically, I'd like to access the MkMapView delegates in my subclass and not in the file that I'm implementing `customSubclass` in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `MKMapView.h` file :

```
@protocol MKMapViewDelegate <NSObject>
@required
// Put your required delegate methods here
-(void)myFirstRequiredMethod;

@optional
// Pute your optional delegate methods here

@end
```

And then you can use the delegate methods in your `customSubClass.m` file :

```
@interface customSubClass : MKMapView <MKMapViewDelegate>

-(void)myFirstRequiredMethod
{
    NSLog(@"Hello");
}

@end
```

c.f. this link for more information : http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/delegate.html

**EDIT ( after comment from OP )**
Sometimes, you don't want to set `self` as the delegate of an object. You can perfectly set an other object as the delegate.

```
    @interface customDelegate : MyCustomDelegateClass <MKMapViewDelegate>

    -(void)myDelegateMethod
    {
        NSLog("hello")
    }

    @end
```

Then, your `customSubClass` should have a property of type `customDelegate`

`customSubClass.h` :

```
@interface customSubClass : MKMapView <MKMapViewDelegate>
{
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) MyCustomDelegateClass  *myCustomDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MKMapView  *myMKMapView;


@end
```

`customSubClass.m` :

```
@implementation MainViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myMKMapView.delegate = self.myCustomDelegate
}
}
```

Comment: If I don't declare the interface in the .h file, I can't access it as a subclass.. So I guess my question was, how do I access it as a subclass in another view controller but send all delegates back to my custom delegate?

Comment: I edited my answer. I am not sure to completely understand what you want to achieve, though

Comment: That looks more like it! Thanks! Shouldn't delegates always be declared weak though due to reference cycles?

Comment: Would be better yes, thanks for the remark, I'll edit my answer immediatelly